# Print log in 0xdbe output

Tags: sql, postgresql, logging, plpgsql, datagrip

I want to know how to print log in 0xdbe console. For exemple, I'm running a *plpgsql* script using **raise notice**, but the notice is printed only after the script finished.

```
DO language plpgsql $$
   DECLARE
   BEGIN
      raise notice 'please datagrip, print this log';
      select count(*) from table_x where name_x like '%xxxx%xxxx%';
END $$;
```

The notice "*please datagrip, print this log*" is printed in output only after script finished.

Thanks for answers.

Comment: This has nothing to do with 0xdbe. This is how Postgres works. The messages from `raise` are only transmitted after the query has finished. It's the same in `psql` or any other client tool.

Comment: You are wrong man, in Navicat, for example, the raise notice is printed on the fly.